# add autocomplete facility for dynamically added input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am creating autocomplete functionality on an input tag  using following code.

```
$('.query').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl:'http://localhost/main/finder.php',
    minChars:2,
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
    maxHeight:400,
    width:400,
    zIndex: 9999,
    deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
    onSelect: function(value, data){
    }
    });
```

Now the problem is my input element is added dynamically so for first input tag autocomplete is working but when i add one more input tag then it fails for the second one.

so i need some facility that live() provide in jquery ...

please do post the solution

Comment: This should help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492198/jquery-auto-complete-for-dynamically-generated-textboxes

Comment: Well i have added following line when dynamically input tag with class 'query' is created

 $(this).children('.query').autocomplete({....});

It works fine as i saw the approach in above link but does this increase the overhead ?

Comment: well the above solution doesn't work as it add autocomplete object everytime

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`livequery` plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs):

```
$('.query').livequery(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        serviceUrl:'http://localhost/main/finder.php',
        minChars:2,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
        maxHeight:400,
        width:400,
        zIndex: 9999,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        onSelect: function(value, data){
        }
    });
});
```

This will run the function whenever new elements matching the selector are added.

Comment: @hunt note that you should make sure that your dynamic page updates are going through the "standard" jQuery APIs.

Comment: well i am using following plugin for jquery http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Comment: How are you changing the content?

Comment: can plz tell me what sort of content r u talking abt ?

Comment: How are you adding the input?

Comment: when i click on a particular div with id "ft" at that time i add input element dynamically  like as follows
$("#ft").live('dblclick',function(){ 
// add input element 
// attach autocomplete 

});

but by attaching autocomplete in a above section is creating a new object of autocomplete everytime ...

Comment: You need to create a new autocomplete object every time.  There is no other way to do it.

Comment: but if i do that thing then eventually there are number of autocomplete tag on my page and at the end they faild to behave in a proper manner ...