# how to implement jquery autocomplete to dynamically generating input text fields

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an input text field

```
 <input type='text' id="vendor_name" name='add_product_vendor_name[]' placeholder='Enter Vendor Name'>
```

with an option to add more vendor name using jquery append function

```
$("#vendor_name").append("<br><input type='text' id="vendor_name"  name='add_product_vendor_name[]' placeholder='Enter Vendor Name'>");
```

I have to implement jquery autocomplete to all the dynamically generating fields, currently Im able to make autocomplete function work on the first field, but im not able to use autocomplete function on the fields that are appended using onclick function. This is the code i use to implement autocomplete

```
   $("#name").autocomplete({

                    source: "<?php echo site_url('product/auto_complete_product'); ?>"  

                });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery auto complete for dynamically generated textboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492198/jquery-auto-complete-for-dynamically-generated-textboxes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach autocomplete after appending input element:

```
$("#vendor_name").append("<br><input type='text' id="name"  name='add_product_vendor_name[]' placeholder='Enter Vendor Name'>");
$("#vendor_name #name").autocomplete({
    source: "<?php echo site_url('product/auto_complete_product'); ?>"  
});
```

Comment: but it will only work for 2 id's right? tht was a typo error in qn. MY form could add name field as many as the client like, right now im trying to make the autocomplete as function and trigger it using a class  than id

Comment: That goes same every time you add the element. just find that element after appending and then use autocomplete with it.