# Dynamic text boxes with autocomplete functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble making dynamic textboxes incorporate the auto complete action. A similar post at: [jquery auto complete for dynamically generated textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492198/jquery-auto-complete-for-dynamically-generated-textboxes) has the idea I want but as I'm still learning the languages needed for this, I don't understand how to incorporate this solution. I could be completely mistaken that the id tag part is the issue. Any help is appreciated.I have a feeling that the auto complete does not run after the page loads but as I said before I am unsure how to fix this. Thanks everyone.

Autocomplete function at the moment:

```
<script>
  $(function bindAutoComplete(classname) {
      var availableTags =[]; //output for autocomplete
      var firstNameArray=[]; //pull first names from database
      var lastNameArray=[];  //pull last names from database
      var combinationFirstName=[]; //seperate array for manipulation and combination
      var combinationLastName=[];  //seperate array for manipulation and combination

      //pulling the data
      firstNameArray="${fullList?.firstName}"; 
      lastNameArray="${fullList?.lastName}";

      //Strip the leading [ and all ,'s from the array still need to remove ]
      combinationFirstName=firstNameArray.split(',');
      combinationFirstName[0]="";
      combinationLastName=lastNameArray.split(',');
      combinationLastName[0]="";

      //combine the two lists
      for (i = 0; i < ${fullList?.firstName?.size()}; i++) { 
          availableTags.push(combinationFirstName[i] + combinationLastName[i])
        }

    $(tags).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
</script>
```

Dynamic boxes at the moment:

```
<script> $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment   
            $(wrapper).append('<div><g:textField name="firstName" id="tags"/><a href="#" class="remove_field"><span> Remove</a></div>');
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
    });
  </script>
```

The HTML also

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Employees</button>
  <div><g:textField name="firstName" id="tags"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I see `$(tags)` is not even a valid selector if you have not made tags a string variable. Maybe you meant `$('#tags')` ?

Comment: I think that is what the code was originally but I thought that related to what I thought was an ID tag problem. I just tried changing it back and it affects the primary box still but none of the dynamic boxes.

Comment: You can´t have more than 1 element with same id

Comment: That's what I was trying to fix but my grasp of the knowledge is so poor I thought the # made it an id tag. Can you think of a way to change it?

Comment: # is just a prefix for id selectors. You should add a class to your textField such as `class='autocomplete'` and then use a class selector: `$(".autocomplete").autocomplete()`

Comment: Ok so it still works as a class now but the dynamic boxes added later still don't receive the autocomplete. Is this due to the page already loaded as I think it does?

Comment: when you do `$(".autocomplete").autocomplete()` it will affect only the created elements in the dom when the function is called. So if you dinamically add more later, you need to run it again for those new elements

Comment: So what should I do to add the auto-complete to the later text fields? Thank you for all your help by the way.

Comment: well, after you append them to the dom, doing `$(".autocomplete").autocomplete()` again is one option

Comment: I don't understand. How would I do it again if the page has already loaded?

Comment: Just do it after $(wrapper).append you have on the onclick method

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! How do I give you credit for this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery plugins in general will initialize whenever you call them, so if you initialize an extension and apply it to some dom elements on document load, all elements of the same selector added dynamically after dom has loaded won´t have the plugin loaded in them. So you need to do it yourself. In your case, it´s an easy case, you are adding new elements on the on click function, so just run the plugin on the elements after adding them to dom:

```
$(wrapper).append(...);
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete()
```

Still, it would be a bit nicer to do:

```
var toAdd = $('<div><g:textField name="firstName" class="autocomplete" id="tags"/><a href="#" class="remove_field"><span> Remove</a></div>')

 $(wrapper).append(toAdd);
 toAdd.autocomplete()
```